# .BAT file cmd commands

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, cmd, sdk

my problem is, i have a bat file and 6 commands. But i cant run. Please help when im gonna crazy :)

**The commands in the bat file like this;**

```
@echo off
1) start cmd.exe cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools (i wanna start cmd under this folder) and then,
2) adb devices (Search connected devices / adroid)
3) adb shell (using shell code)
4) su (connect superuser to android phone)
5) svc data disable (disable phone mobile data)
6) exit (close bat and cmd file)
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem besides the unneeded line numbers and "comments" in parentheses? Don't answer in comments, edit the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all line numbers,comments in parenthesis, the "and then,", start cmd.exe and replace `username` with `%username%`.

Overall looks like:

```
@echo off
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
adb devices
adb shell
su
svc data disable
exit
```